# What does the no-hair theorem state about the entropy of black holes?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, entropy, astrophysics, no-hair-theorem

So does the no hair theorem say that all classical black holes will have zero entropy? If yes, why?

Comment: Please provide additional details to make the question self-contained. For example, could you summarize the no-hair problem and specify its relation to the black hole theory?

Answer (score 2):

The no hair theorem is a statement about steady-state vacuum solutions in classical general relativity. It says that once a black hole has settled down to a steady state (by radiating away any dynamic features by gravitational radiation) the solution in the vacuum depends on only a small number of parameters (mass, charge, momentum, angular momentum, and possibly magnetic charge in a theory allowing for magnetic monopoles). In this description the black hole has zero entropy.

The above classical description is believed to be inaccurate however. By bringing in quantum field theory one can mount a strong case that a large amount of entropy is associated with a black hole. One can make this case even without a complete theory of quantum gravity. So we now think that black holes have a non-zero temperature and a very large entropy. The large entropy in turn implies that there is a huge number of microstates which together are consistent with any given set of macroscopic parameters such as $m,Q,{\bf p},{\bf J}$. This implies that by specifying only the macroscopic parameters one does not in fact determine the full details of the state. One could indeed assert that the implication is that instead of 'no hair' a black hole has a huge amount of 'hair', in the sense that a huge amount of information would be needed if one wished to completely specify its state in microscopic detail. Or, to say the same thing another way: if one wished to send a large amount of information from one place to another, one could in principle do so by sending a black hole. This form of communication would only be practical if the sender had the technology to pick one microstate at the sending end, and the receiver had the technology to distinguish among microstates. I mention it as a thought-experiment which serves to clarify the sense in which a black hole may be said to have a lot of 'hair'.

*Added remarks in response to comments*

*Safesphere* correctly points out that the no-hair theorem is strictly a theorem about vacuum solutions, so it is questionable whether it applies to any astrophysical object. This is because a black hole formed by gravitational collapse of matter is not quite the same as an 'eternal' black hole. The latter is a solution of the field equations in an artificial case where we ignore cosmic expansion and just come up with a solution which never involved any matter falling in; the horizon is simply there into the infinite past. In classical GR the no-hair theorem applies to artificial solutions of that kind, but one can argue that it does not apply, even in classical GR, to the case of a black hole with matter falling in.

My thought-experiment involving selecting a microstate for a black hole is very much a thought-experiment. It is comparable to having a collection of oscillators whose motions have a variety of phases and amplitudes, and selecting one particular phase and amplitude for each oscillator.

Comment: Also *momentum* ? Are there black holes endowed with linear  momentum $p$?

Comment: @ValterMoretti yes: start in the rest frame of your black hole (i.e. the frame where the asymptotic region is like Newtonian gravity from a non-moving source). In that frame the momentum is zero. Now change to some other inertial frame. In the new frame the black hole's linear momentum is non-zero.

Comment: I understand but I am not sure that the other constants have a similar interpretation. For instance the angular momentum of a bh exists in absolute sense because there is a certain Killing vector in the spacetime associated to the rotation group around an axis. This is not an approximate feature. Your notion of linear momentum is only approximate instead. There are no corresponding Killing vector fields because they are not compatible with the notion of black hole.

Comment: @ValterMoretti There is a complete energy-momentum 4-vector. How could there not be? (c.f. Komar integral). The Killing vector field is in the $t$ direction in asymptotic region of the standard Schwarzschild soln (for non-rotating hole)  in Schw coordinates. Apply a Lorentz transformation and you have the Killing vector field in some other frame.

Comment: No, I do not think so.  A Killing vector associated to a spatial momentum should  be spacelike. The Killing vector of the external region of a Schwarzschild black hole is timelike.  And this property (timelike)  cannot be changed by changing the reference frame. In the external region of a S. bh there is no spatial translational symmetry. At most there is an approximate translational symmetry far from the black hole. Conversely there is an *exact* temporal symmetry. The no hair theorem refers to exact symmetries only.

Comment: @safesphere: why would there _be_ an information paradox to begin with if classical general relativity is sufficient to account for the supposedly "missing" information - it being right there, trapped at the horizon "forever"?

Comment: @ValterMoretti I see what you mean about spacelike etc; I wrote a bit too hastily. But if I stand on some planet somewhere, and there are two black holes nearby, both with the same $m,Q,{\bf J}$, then if one is moving towards me and the other is not then I can tell the difference between them.

Comment: @safesphere : Thanks. I am also curious though - how exactly can/do you define a _coordinate-free_ (as you seem to be implying exists given you suggest matters like foliation and simultaneity, which are fundamentally about choices of coordinates, are irrelevant) notion of the matter "being trapped at the horizon" in classical GR, given that the most natural coordinate-free choice of object to study is the worldline of a falling object, and all of those end up at the singularity, not stopping at the horizon?

Comment: @The_Sympathizer In a hyperbolic spacetime, causality is not coordinate dependent. No event of crossing the horizon is in the past light cone of any external event, including the complete evaporation event. This means the black hole evaporates before anything crosses the horizon in any coordinate system. So matter must be destroyed just outside the horizon by some quantum process. Energy, momentum, spin, and electric charge remain, but all other information (quantum numbers) disappear.

Answer (score 1):

The no hair theorem says that a black hole is uniquely identified by few parameters (mass, charge, angular momentum). By itself, there are no implications on the entropy, as different microstates may contribute to the same thermodynamical macrostate described by (M, Q, L).

(Disclaimer following comments: the next paragraph is describing an idealised mathemetical version of a black hole, not a physical one)

Still, in the classical picture (no quantum fields, no evaporation) of a black hole with a pointlike singularity at the center, all the absorbed matter fall into the singularity and leave no trace. Therefore there is only a microstate, $W=1$, equal to the macrostate (M, Q, L=0). The statistical entropy of this black hole is $S \propto log(W) = 0$.

Comment: This answer is incorrect and is based on a number of misconceptions. A singularity is not pointlike. A black hole does not have a center. Nothing inside the horizon (including the singularity) has any effect outside and cannot define the entropy. All external properties of a black hole are defined by the horizon, not by anything inside. As observed from outside, matter never crosses the horizon. A zero entropy would violate the laws of thermodynamics. Here is a classical derivation of the black hole entropy and it is not zero: https://www.slac.stanford.edu/pubs/slacpubs/4000/slac-pub-4061.pdf

Comment: In the second paragraph, we are talking about different scenarios. I'm talking about no evaporation (that is the black hole emits nothing, there is no concept of temperature) and computing the statistical entropy. The paper you referenced starts assuming that classical thermodynamics is valid for a black hole and goes on finding something in agreement with bekenstein area entropy. I've fixed a typo, it should be L=0. It goes without saying that I'm not claiming that S=0 for real black holes.

Comment: I think this is almost the opposite of the correct answer.  What the No Hair Theorem implies about thermodynamics is that there are very few macro-states of a black hole; the macro-state is determined only a tiny number of parameters:  mass, angular momentum, and gauge charges.  Yet to each of these macro-states there corresponds a vast number of micro-states, which is why the $S$ of a black hole is so large.  This is true even classically, since there are a vast number of initial states that, per GR, collapse into a black hole, not just the primordial black hole assumed in this answer.

Comment: From wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem): The no-hair theorem states that all stationary black hole solutions of the Einstein–Maxwell equations of gravitation and electromagnetism in general relativity can be **completely** characterized by only three independent externally observable classical parameters: mass, electric charge, and angular momentum.[1] Other characteristics (such as geometry and magnetic moment) are uniquely determined by these three parameters, and **all other information (for which "hair" is a metaphor) ...

Comment: ... about the matter that formed a black hole or is falling into it "disappears" behind the black-hole event horizon and is therefore **permanently inaccessible** to external observers after the black hole "settles down" (by emitting gravitational and electromagnetic waves).

Comment: Are you claiming that you can access the microstate on the horizon from the outside and retrieve the information?

Comment: Or perhaps are you referring to Black hole complementarity?

Comment: I think you are saying that Kerr-Newman solutions are not physical black holes, since formally real black holes never completely settle to them. But the facto they are very good approximations, and given Kerr-Newman there is just isn't any structure that can give more than one microstate. They have no memory of how they have been formed.

Comment: But you could argue that they never formed in the first place, so of course they have no memory.